# Can I publish a crate that uses a patch?

Tags: c, rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

The section in the Rust documentation that talks about [patching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#overriding-dependencies) explains how to implement a patch, but all of the examples it uses are for "testing" and short term fixing. What I want to do is make a patch for one of the crates I depend on that bumps its sub-dependencies, *and then I would then like to publish my crate with its patched dependencies on `crates.io`*. However, when you create a patch you have to list a path dependency, as in the example:

```
[patch.crates-io]
uuid = { path = "../path/to/uuid" }
```

I assume this would prevent me from publishing my crate, since I now have a dependency on something not in `crates.io`.

So overall my question is: can I publish a crate to `crates.io` that uses a local patch? If not, is there another workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It is not possible](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies)

> Note: crates.io does not allow packages to be published with path dependencies (path dev-dependencies are ignored). See the Multiple locations section for a fallback alternative.
>
> It is possible to specify both a registry version and a git or path location. The git or path dependency will be used locally (in which case the version is checked against the local copy), and when published to a registry like crates.io, it will use the registry version. Other combinations are not allowed.

You will need to have the dependency uploaded to crates.io.

Comment: The link you posted refers to crates listed under the `[dependencies]` section in `Cargo.toml`, but I'm talking about crates listed under the `[patch.crates-io]` section. Does this still apply?

Comment: @Migwell I don't see anything on [the page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html) that says you can or can't. You may have to try it yourself.

Comment: Indeed. If I try it using `cargo publish --dry-run` it uses the original Cargo version of the crate without my patches, meaning that the build fails. So it looks like you can't publish using a patch.